# Choose Unique Row and Previous Value Within Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I'm using a table that some times repeats the same data and I'd like to query it to get just the most recent value and the value before it.  The table is like so:

```
+-------------+----------------+------+-------+
| Item Number | Effective Date | Cost | Price |
+-------------+----------------+------+-------+
|      1      |   01/01/2020   | 8.00 | 11.00 |
|      1      |   01/01/2020   | 8.00 | 10.50 |
|      2      |   09/22/2020   | 6.25 |  6.50 |
|      1      |   01/01/2020   | 8.00 | 10.50 |
|      1      |   05/07/2019   | 7.00 | 10.50 |
|      1      |   03/12/2018   | 6.00 | 10.50 |
|      2      |   03/12/2018   | 6.00 |  6.50 |
|      2      |   03/12/2018   | 6.00 |  6.50 |
|      1      |   01/01/2020   | 7.00 | 10.50 |
|      1      |   08/01/2016   | 5.25 | 10.50 |
+-------------+----------------+------+-------+
```

I'm try to get the query results to list the date of just the most recent cost and the date and cost be of the one before it and ignore all the duplicates of the data like this:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Item Number | Previous Date | Previous Cost | Current Date | Current Cost |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1      |   05/07/2019  |     7.00      |  01/01/2020  |     8.00     |
|      2      |   03/12/2018  |     6.00      |  09/22/2020  |     6.50     |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've been struggling with lag and partitioning but, I'm still getting the duplicates like this:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Item Number | Previous Date | Previous Cost | Current Date | Current Cost |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1      |   01/20/2020  |     8.00      |  01/01/2020  |     8.00     |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Thanks for any ideas you have!

Comment: Does `Effective Date` have a time component? If not, how do you know which of the 4 different 01/01/2020 records is the latest for item 1?

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a question template greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer.  In this case actual table description (ddl if possible) and the current/best query. It is understood it is not working. Also, for your sample data how do you determine the Current_Date and Cost (assuming current_date corresponds to "most recent" from your description). You have 5 rows for item_number 1 and date 2020-01-01, with different cast values.

Comment: Correct.  There are multiple rows where the item, date, and cost are the same.  That's the problem.  For the results I need, they're all considered equal and  I need the record before the most recent date to be the previous.

Comment: So, like I put in the example result: 01/01/20 is the most recent cost of 8.00 for item 1.  Before that?  It was 7.00 and effective on 5/7/2019.  There is no current nor best query, just a warm bucket of fail.

Comment: But  what in the data tells that 01/01/2020 cost 8.00 is more recent than 01/01/2020 cost 7.00?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to see the last two records for each item number whenever descendingly ordered by the date column. I prepared this grouping and ordering along with eliminating the duplicated rows by using `DISTINCT` in the below query, but we don't know which cost is the recent for the common date as Belayer spotted. I just considered the maximum one as your result and the nature of inflation :) .

I determined the previous and current columns by contribution of `ROW_NUMBER()` function in the last step :

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Number, Effective_Date) AS Cost,
        Item_Number, Effective_Date
   FROM tab 
  ORDER BY Item_Number, Effective_Date 
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT t1.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Number ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC) AS rn
   FROM t1  
)
SELECT Item_Number, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Effective_Date END) AS Previous_Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Cost END) AS Previous_Cost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Effective_Date END) AS Current_Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Cost END) AS Current_Cost       
  FROM t2   
 WHERE rn <= 2 
 GROUP BY Item_Number;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7275bcc8fc22b436879670bc1e68084a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest for you the following approach.

```
with
    date_t as
    (
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 8.00 as cost, 11.00 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 8.00 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual union all
        select 2 as item_number, to_date('09/22/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 6.25  as cost, 6.50 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 8.00 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('05/07/2019','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 7.00 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('03/12/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 6.00 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual union all
        select 2 as item_number, to_date('03/12/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 6.00  as cost, 6.50 as price from dual union all
        select 2 as item_number, to_date('03/12/2018','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 6.00  as cost, 6.50 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 7.00 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual union all
        select 1 as item_number, to_date('08/01/2016','mm/dd/yyyy') as effective_date, 5.25 as cost, 10.50 as price from dual 
    )
select 
    item_number,
    lag(effective_date) over (partition by item_number order by effective_date) as previous_date,
    lag(cost) over (partition by item_number order by effective_date) as previous_cost,
    effective_date as current_date,
    cost as current_cost
from    
    (
        select
            item_number,
            effective_date,
            max(cost) as cost
        from
            date_t  
        group by
            item_number,
            effective_date
        order by effective_date desc
    ) t
```

The output will be look like this.

```
ITEM_NUMBER PREVIOUS_DATE   PREVIOUS_COST   CURRENT_DATE    CURRENT_COST
----------- -------------   -------------   ------------     ----------- 
1             null          null            01.08.2016       5.25
1             01.08.2016    5.25            12.03.2018       6
1             12.03.2018    6               07.05.2019       7
1             07.05.2019    7               01.01.2020       8
2             null          null            12.03.2018       6
2             12.03.2018    6               22.09.2020       6.25
```

**Note:** I have the other date format in Oracle is `dd.mm.yyyy`.